# How to split dataframe in half by keeping 1 record and drop another record on all records?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with over 200k records.

I wish to slim my dataframe down by half, by dropping one record for each that I keep (as is displayed below).

```
Keep Row 1,
Drop Row 2,
Keep Row 3,
Drop Row 4,
Keep Row 5,
and so on and so forth...
```

If this is not possible then I am more than willing to use pandas sample functionality in conjunction with a mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `slicing` with this formula like that you want `[1::2]` `([start:end:step])`, here start from 1 and step is 2, So : `1,3,5,....`. Because you have `dataframe`, you can use `df.index[1::2]`. So you can *keep 1*, *drop 2*, *keep 3*, *drop 4*, ....

*(index start from zero and if you want to start from zero you can try with `[::2]`)*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : np.random.randint(0,10,1000),
    'B' : np.random.randint(0,10,1000)
})
print(df)

df = df.iloc[df.index[1::2]]
print(df)
```

---

```
#input random df
     A  B
0    1  8
1    5  4
2    8  4
3    9  0
4    9  5
..  .. ..
995  8  9
996  4  9
997  8  4
998  2  8
999  9  0

[1000 rows x 2 columns]

# result random df
     A  B
1    5  4
3    9  0
5    6  8
7    4  1
9    6  6
..  .. ..
991  1  5
993  6  8
995  8  9
997  8  4
999  9  0

[500 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: OP wants to keep the first row, so `::2` is even simpler. This is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Thanks for your advice, I add more information in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can index with a mask like `mask = (1 - np.arange(len(df)) % 2).astype(bool)`.

- You can remove the `1 -` if you're ok to start dropping with the first record instead of the second.
- If you have a numerical index, you can replace `np.arange(len(df))` with `df.index`.
- You can replace `...astype(bool)` with `... == 0`, `... == 1`, or even `np.logical_not(...)`.